# How to convert image to tensor in Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a webpage where I can select and display a local image, alongside a prediction made by a TensorFlow model. To feed the image to the model it needs to be in a tensor with values for each pixel. How can I convert the image to a tensor of pixel values? The example code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.7.0"> </script>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.5.1/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
    <title>display image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
      <p id="result">Prediction </p>
      <p><img id="output" width="200"/></p>
      <script>
          var loadFile = function(event) {
              var image = document.getElementById('output');
              image.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
          };
          //Some method to convert the image into a tensor
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [`tf.browser.fromPixels`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#browser.fromPixels) ?

```
image.onload = () => {
  const imgTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image);
  ...
}
```